# как оптимизировать прохождение графа

Tags: c#, оптимизация, графы

На codewars.com есть задача по поиску выхода из лабиринта.
*https://www.codewars.com/kata/5765870e190b1472ec0022a2/train/csharp*.
Mой код может пройти все лабиринты из тестов, но он делает это медленно. Как можно оптимизировать код?  Пробовал сделать ещё один список который проходит лабиринт от выхода и возвращает `true`  если у двух списков есть общий елемент. Но пройти все тесты за нужное время не получается.

```
    public static bool PathFinder(string maze)
    {
        int row = (int)Math.Sqrt(maze.Length + 1) + 1;

        List<int> list = new List<int>() { 0 };

        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            if (!list.Contains(list[i] + 1) && list[i] + 1 < maze.Length + 1 && maze[list[i] + 1] == '.') list.Add(list[i] + 1);
            if (!list.Contains(list[i] + row) && list[i] + row < maze.Length && maze[list[i] + row] == '.') list.Add(list[i] + row);
            if (!list.Contains(list[i] - 1) && list[i] - 1 > 0 && maze[list[i] - 1] == '.') list.Add(list[i] - 1);
            if (!list.Contains(list[i] - row) && list[i] - row > 0 && maze[list[i] - row] == '.') list.Add(list[i] - row);

            if (list.Contains(maze.Length - 1)) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для решения вашей задачи подойдет любой обход графа, хоть в ширину, хоть в глубину, хоть что то среднее между ними.

Я написал просто обход графа через очередь (что то типа поиска в ширину) и все спокойно отработало

```
public class Finder
{
    public static bool PathFinder(string maze)
    {
        if (maze.Length == 1) return true;
        var N = maze.IndexOf('\n');

        var q = new Queue<(int x, int y)>();
        var visited = new HashSet<(int, int)>();

        var destination = (N - 1, N - 1);

        q.Enqueue((0, 0));

        while (q.Count > 0)
        {
            var curr = q.Dequeue();         

            if (curr == destination) return true;           

            CheckCoords((curr.x + 1, curr.y), N, maze, q, visited);
            CheckCoords((curr.x - 1, curr.y), N, maze, q, visited);
            CheckCoords((curr.x, curr.y + 1), N, maze, q, visited);
            CheckCoords((curr.x, curr.y - 1), N, maze, q, visited);
        }
        return false;
    }
    
    private static void CheckCoords((int x, int y) coord, int N, string maze, Queue<(int x, int y)> q, HashSet<(int, int)> visited)
    {
        if (coord.x < 0 || coord.x >= N) return;
        if (coord.y < 0 || coord.y >= N) return;
        
        var coord1D = Trans2Dto1D(coord, N);

        if (maze[coord1D] == '.' && !visited.Contains(coord))
        {
            q.Enqueue(coord);
            visited.Add(coord);
        }
    }

    private static int Trans2Dto1D((int x, int y) coord, int N)
    {
        return coord.x * N + coord.y + (coord.x > 0 ? coord.x : 0);
    }
}
```

Конкретно в вашем примере, я не оч понимаю, что вы делаете, но вот эта операция `list.Contains` явно медленная, так как поиск по списку занимает линейное время. Ищите по хешсету и у вас будет шанс уложиться во время. Как то так это может выглядеть

```
public static bool PathFinder(string maze)
{
    if (maze.Length == 1) return true;
    int row = (int)Math.Sqrt(maze.Length + 1) + 1;

    List<int> list = new List<int>() { 0 };
    var set = new HashSet<int>();
    set.Add(0);
    

    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        if (!set.Contains(list[i] + 1) && list[i] + 1 < maze.Length + 1 && maze[list[i] + 1] == '.')
        {
            list.Add(list[i] + 1);
            set.Add(list[i] + 1);
        }

        if (!set.Contains(list[i] + row) && list[i] + row < maze.Length && maze[list[i] + row] == '.')
        {
            list.Add(list[i] + row);
            set.Add(list[i] + row);
        }

        if (!set.Contains(list[i] - 1) && list[i] - 1 > 0 && maze[list[i] - 1] == '.')
        {
            list.Add(list[i] - 1);
            set.Add(list[i] - 1);
        }

        if (!set.Contains(list[i] - row) && list[i] - row > 0 && maze[list[i] - row] == '.')
        {
            list.Add(list[i] - row);
            set.Add(list[i] - row);
        }

        if (set.Contains(maze.Length - 1)) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```